# Creating dynamic persistence models from database metadata

Tags: java, database, jpa

We have a document management application and a part of it is having customized document forms for the customer to enter document metadata and save it to his database. To create these forms we have developed a 3rd party proprietary application which takes care of the design of the forms (where the fields go, what type they are etc) and then takes this design and creates dynamic tables to represent it in the database. Each form is represented by 3 tables:

- Table_A contains information about the form's fields. This table has a standard format and each row in the table represents one of the form's fields.
- Table_B contains information about the design. This table also has a standard format and each row contains information about each field's position when dynamically creating the form at runtime.
- Table_C contains information about the metadata the user entered when he saved a document in the system. This table does NOT have a standard format. It is dynamically created by the 3rd party software and its `columns` are dynamic in both number and type. In one form `column_A` might be an integer and in another form `column_A` might be a date. One table might have 10 columns while another might have 70. It all depends on the form it represents.

The problem we have at the moment is that we want to add JPA to our project. However, in order to work JPA requires that all persistence models are defined in the xml or through annotations, which is impossible for us because our application doesn't know beforehand the design of `Table_C` for each form. When we want to retrieve data from that table we actually query `Table_A`, find out how many fields there are and then build a query dynamically according to the result and query `Table_C` for its metadata. This technique is impossible to execute in `JPQL` since it needs concrete objects to create queries. My question is, would it be possible to create persistence models dynamically using `DatabaseMetaData` and Java's Reflection API?

TL;DR: Is it possible to create `JPA` persistence models at runtime by reading `DatabaseMetaData` and using Java's Reflection API?

Comment: What would be the benefit to create such model classes dynamically? How would you use such classes, when you don't know what fields they have in advance? As far as I can see it doesn't make any sense to use JPA for such a use case.

Comment: We would like to take advantage of JPA's caching, pagination and other such querying features that would really benefit us when asking for data from the client side.